# Will Nasa take the opportunity for another one year ISS mission now?

Tags: iss, crewed-spaceflight

Since the Soyuz MS-10 in October will only have  two persons aboard, it would be a great opportunity for space science on the ISS to
let Richard Arnold continue his mission for another 6 months until the return of Soyuz MS-10 (exactly the same situation as 
before with Peggy Whitson).  Are there  negotiations with Roscosmos on this?

Answer (score 3):

Richard Arnold returned with the rest of his Soyuz MS-08 crew  after 196 days in space.

Since then, no crew was or is planned to stay for at least a year.  Christina Koch stayed the longest *during this period*, 328 days.  (Scott Kelly stayed 340 days, but that was *prior* to this question.)  Two of the future Soyuz MS-19 crew are planned to stay 354 days.

[Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ISS_Expeditions)

Comment: Perhaps you meant Soyuz Ms-19? Because of the shooting of a film on the ISS, Pyotr Dubrov and Mark Vand Hei will have a prolonged stay.

Comment: Yes.  How is that not what I wrote?

Comment: My bad, I could have sworn I saw MS-18 there.